# Stripe charge in C#.NET 4.6

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I installed the latest stripe library from nuget. This is original Stripe library for .NET.

I had the same older library and exsisting code was working OK. The latest library doesn't support those classes. How to charge as exsisting code with the latest library?

```
    public void ChargeStripe(string stripeEmail, string stripeToken, string payAmount, string 
                             currency, string customerId, string paymentDescription) 
                                 
    {
        // public ActionResult Charge(string stripeEmail, string stripeToken)
        var customers = new StripeCustomerService();
        var charges = new StripeChargeService();

        var customer = customers.Create(new StripeCustomerCreateOptions
        {
            Email = stripeEmail,
            SourceToken = stripeToken
        });

        var charge = charges.Create(new StripeChargeCreateOptions
        {
            Amount = payAmount,  // charge in cents
            Description = paymentDescription,
            Currency = currency,
            CustomerId = customerId
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why are you targeting .NET 4.6? It's an obsolete version that doesn't truly support .NET Standard 2.0. Is there a reason you can't retarget to .NET 4.8?

Comment: @Dani .NET 4.6 is not obsolete (https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/lifecycle/search?alpha=.net%20framework). It supports also .NET Standard 2.0 but yes, it brings many satellite dll's, but it doesn't brake code.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at [Stripe changelog](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). I see that they changed some names between versions. Probably you will need only to change them.